# How can i limit a Knockout foreach on an observable array to 5 at a time without using computed observables?

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observable array which I want to use to populate a table, but I only want the first 5 from the list to be displayed on the table at any given moment. When I try using a computed observable it makes the code longer, I wanna achieve this while still keeping the code neat and simple.

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        ko.applyBindings({
            people: [
                { firstName: 'Bert', lastName: 'Bertington' },
                { firstName: 'Charles', lastName: 'Charlesforth' },
                { firstName: 'Author', lastName: 'Dentiste' },
                { firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Depth' },
                { firstName: 'Arnold', lastName: 'Carol' },
                { firstName: 'Ritchie', lastName: 'Dentiste' },
                { firstName: 'Denise', lastName: 'Lemel' }
            ]
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the virtual `if` binding in HTML? Not the most performance efficient, but it's only 1 line of code.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
            <!-- ko if: ($index() < 5) -->
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button data-bind="click: killBert">Kill Bert</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var viewmodel = {
            people: ko.observableArray([
                { firstName: 'Bert', lastName: 'Bertington' },
                { firstName: 'Charles', lastName: 'Charlesforth' },
                { firstName: 'Author', lastName: 'Dentiste' },
                { firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Depth' },
                { firstName: 'Arnold', lastName: 'Carol' },
                { firstName: 'Ritchie', lastName: 'Dentiste' },
                { firstName: 'Denise', lastName: 'Lemel' }
            ])
        };
        viewmodel.killBert = function (){
          viewmodel.people.remove(function(person){
            return person.firstName === 'Bert';
          });
        };
        ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
        
    </script>
```

Comment: what if an item in the Table get deleted, would the Table be updated with the next item in the Observable Array ?

Comment: Yes, but first we have to make people an observableArray. I've updated answer

Comment: sir please can you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53060270/how-can-i-constantly-update-a-value-databinded-to-a-view-in-knockout/53060927#53060927